# Snapshot collection in .NET app frees the memory, what is happening behind the scenes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-leaks

I'm investigating a memory leak in a .NET Winforms application and when collecting a snapshot with my tool I noticed the memory got freed (1GB to 1mb).

Here come my doubts... Is it really a memory leak? What is the .NET profiler doing when collecting a snapshot that my application is not? Is it forcing the Garbage Collection? If so I tried doing the same with GC.Collect() but the memory still kept rising.

Looking forward to your considerations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with `GC.Collect()` because it *does NOT* trigger actual garbage collecting. It only tells `GC` that it would be good to trigger. You can find more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals?redirectedfrom=MSDN#conditions_for_a_garbage_collection

You can try with:

```
GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
```

Where `2` is garbage collection generation

Comment: I figured that out, what can I try to force it actually? If the profiler can do it then there can be a way for me right?

Comment: thanks, but reading the documentation it seems like the forced enum is the default one. but i could try it anyway